# I want to enter password when application delete in ios 5

Tags: ios

iam doing a Mobile Application of platform in iphone(mostly ios 5) i want to enter  password when my app is delete.did anybody knows how its working.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done from an AppStore app. If jailbreaking is an option, you can hook SpringBoard to make the user enter a password.